# System.Drawing.Image: When does data (de)compression occur for compressed images?

Tags: .net, system.drawing

I did not tag this question as TIFF because I imagine that .NET would treat the behavior the same way for different image types, which may also have compression.

I'm working on a server that manipulates some TIFF images.  It does so by using Bitmap.LockBits, and using unsafe pointer data manipulation.  These images are compressed using the TIFF G4 format, which .NET handles behind the scenes.

When using Bitmap.LockBits, the pixel data that is then made available through pointers, is in the uncompressed format.

My question is, when does this data become decompressed?

1) When loading the image into a System.Drawing.Image object from file or stream?

2) When using Bitmap.LockBits?

3) When creating a Graphics object from the given image?

Ideally, I only want the system to decompress the data one time per image, but I need to know what's happening under the hood in order to ensure that.

Comment: You'll need to do experiments to figure this out yourself.  Load the bitmap file into a MemoryStream, load it with Image.FromStream(), then Dispose() the stream.  That *sometimes* generates an exception when you next try to use the Image object.  But not consistent enough, exactly when GDI+ decides to go lazy is hard to guess and it depends on the codec.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you know of any literature or docs on this subject that could help here?

Comment: Yes, there is none.  Quite intentional, when Microsoft documents internals of a library then they can never change it again.  It is in general quite unwise to rely on internals, GDI+ is however unlikely to change in the future.  Last time it was touched was 10 years ago.

Comment: @HansPassant Doesn't have to be from Microsoft.  I know you have a lot of points here but I like to have concrete evidence before making major engineering decisions.